# Неверный ответ при решении в С#

Tags: c#, math

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при решении уравнения выводит не тот ответ: 2,9848, а должно быть: 1.9873
Ниже приводится код:

```
Double x = 0.4 * Math.Pow(10.0, 4);
        Double y = -0.875;
        Double z = -0.475 * Math.Pow(10.0, -3);

        Double stepen = 1 + 2 * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(y), 2);
        Double cosinus = Math.Abs(Math.Cos(x) - Math.Cos(y));
        Double vozvedenie_v_stepen = cosinus * stepen;

        Double Z = 1 + z + (Math.Pow(z, 2)/2) + (Math.Pow(z, 3)/3) + (Math.Pow(z, 4)/4);

        Double full_formula = vozvedenie_v_stepen * Z;

        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(full_formula, 4));
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Где я неправильно решил?

Comment: К сожалению, не учили меня в универе. Сам учусь программировать.

Comment: вот и хорошо, программирования без отладки не бывает, успехов вам в наступающем году.

Comment: @Bulson не надо относится свысока к новичкам. В данном вопросе видно, что человек прикладывал усилия, пытаясь решить задачу. А если вы чего-то знаете, чего новичок не знает, то лучше спокойно поделитесь, а то полезность этого комментария равна нулю.

Comment: @Bulson, извините, что вызвал ваше недовольство, и тем, что я явился причиной критики Вас другими членами сообщества. Просто я не обращал внимание на отладку типа "Ставить точки останова, проходить исполнение по шагам, смотреть значения локальных переменных". После вашего замечания буду смотреть внимательнее.

Comment: @Bulson Я, к примеру, чистый самоучка, и как отлаживать никто не учил. Изучил очень много по C#, но как отлаживать узнал когда устроился на вторую работу. До это `Console.WriteLine` отлаживал:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо

> `Double vozvedenie_v_stepen = cosinus * stepen;`

Должно быть

```
Double vozvedenie_v_stepen = Math.Pow(cosinus, stepen);
```